# Получить данные и построить объект из таблицы бд с неизвестным количеством столбцов

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

Всем привет! 
Java(7) + Spring + Hibernate + JDBC + OracleDB.
Есть задача реализовать способ получения данных из таблиц базы данных. Известно лишь имя таблицы. Ни количество столбцов, ни какого они типа - неизвестно. Таблицы генерируются по разному. 
В какую сторону копать? Можно как то получить коллекцию (какой-то объект) строчек из таблицы и распарсить, к примеру, в мапу(ключ: имя колонки, значение: лист данных)?

Comment: задача похожа на: "пойди туда, не знаю куда, принеси то, не знаю что"

Comment: Если совсем просто, то кроме имени таблицы ничего не надо, т.к. `select * from <table_name>` получить все столбцы. Если требуется точно знать названия и тип, то есть куча метаданных в таблицах: USER_TABLES, USER_TAB_COLS И т.д.

Comment: Да, спасибо. С запросом было все понятно. Т.е можно сначала получить данные о таблице с каких-то служебных таблиц и на основе этих данных построить объект в который будут сетатся данные?

Comment: Да, все верно, можно полностью сгенерировать запрос, зная имя таблицы.

Comment: Пробовали выполнять запрос через JDBC? Запрос возвращает [курсор](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), у которого можно прочитать [метаданные](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) (столбцы и их типы). По сути это и есть нужная Вам коллекция.

Comment: @defaultlocale Спасибо. Я присмотрелся и действительно похоже что именно это мне и нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так можно получить мета данные, либо по имени таблицы #1 [DatabaseMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html), либо из курсора когда имя таблицы неизвестно #2 [ResultSetMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) :

```
import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
import java.sql.*;

public class TestMetaData {
    public static void main (String[] args) { try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@srv/svc", "hr", "hr");
        //#1
        DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
        ResultSet cols = md.getColumns (null, "HR", "EMPLOYEES", "%NAME%");
        while (cols.next ()) {
            System.out.println (cols.getString ("column_name")+": "+cols.getString ("type_name"));
        }
        //#2
        CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall ("begin  getDepartment (?, ?);  end;"); 
        cs.setInt (1, 10);
        cs.registerOutParameter (2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cs.execute ();
        ResultSet rset = (ResultSet)cs.getObject (2);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rset.getMetaData (); 
        for (int i=1; i<=rsmd.getColumnCount (); i++) {
            System.out.println (rsmd.getColumnLabel (i)+": "+rsmd.getColumnTypeName (i));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }}
}
```

Вывод будет выгядеть как-то так:

```
FIRST_NAME: VARCHAR2
LAST_NAME: VARCHAR2
DEPARTMENT_ID: NUMBER
DEPARTMENT_NAME: VARCHAR2
MANAGER_ID: NUMBER
LOCATION_ID: NUMBER
```